# Wordpress sql query results vs sql query in phpmyadmin query different order

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm bit confused about wordpress, i have following query to calculate distance between posts :

```
public function distance($latitude, $longitude){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT l.post_id,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( l.latitude ) ) 
       * cos( radians(l.longitude) - radians($longitude)) + sin(radians($latitude)) 
       * sin( radians(l.latitude)))) AS distance 
    FROM localisation as l
    HAVING distance < 50
    ORDER BY distance ASC";
    $output = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
    dump($output) // <--- Here i test the result

}
```

The output displays the posts from the closest to the farthest (around 50km) except that when I copy/paste the same query I don't have the same result (the products are ordered from the closest to the farthest but not the same order)

Output from this query :

```
post_id. | distance. 
1245       0.25029229952593496
8547       0.25029229952593496
78451      0.25029229952593496
45874      0.4428014744990856
```

But output from phpmyadmin :

```
post_id. | distance. 
78451      0.25029229952593496
8547       0.25029229952593496
1245       0.25029229952593496
45874      0.4428014744990856
```

Order are not the same, even sorting is good

Have you an idea? why i have get different order ?

Thank you

Comment: Since three of the records show the _exact_ same distance, you need to add a secondary order column to make sure they are returned in the same order. Without it, you're not telling MySQL how to order identical values, so you can never assume what order they come in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because you should order by 'distance' first and then you should order by 'id'. Php my admin ordered  by id 'DESC' by default but wp ordered it by id 'ASC',
You should try in you wp query something like this

```
ORDER BY distance ASC, ID ASC
```

or

```
ORDER BY distance ASC, ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

ORDER both column.

ORDER BY
post_id ASC, distance ASC if you want the first result

Comment: It should be the other way around. Distance first and id second. Otherwise, it will only order by id (since no two posts can have the same id, it will never order by distance)